# What is the difference between {block} and {include}?

Tags: smarty

What are the main differences between the {block} tag and the {include} tag? I know they are both used for template inheritance, but does one work faster or allow for more flexibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`{include}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl) function simply refers to another template file whose contents should be included at that point in the output. It is not related to any kind of inheritance, and works like a cross between PHP's `include`/`require` and a function call, in that you can pass in parameters and variables can have local scope.

The `{block}` function is used for [Template Inheritance](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.template.inheritance.tpl). While the effects could be simulated by clever use of sub-templates, the fundamental idea is very different. As explained in the documentation, a parent template can have a number of named blocks, and a child template can over-ride any or all of these, referencing them by name, with the remainder of the code coming directly from the parent template.

One way of thinking about it would be that `{include}` is useful if you have sections of content you want to include into multiple page structures, whereas Template Inheritance would be more appropriate if you want many pages with similar structure, but with different content in certain sections. And of course, you may well want a mixture of both.